# Nested List Binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a noob problem when binding a list within a list

I'm trying to follow this* tutorial, and I'm having a bit of trouble rendering data for the inner list

*http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

see code at 
http://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/K7kcc/

```
var landing = function () {
  this.displayName = 'Welcome to my ko/Durandal? Data Entry Kit!';
  this.description = 'This ko/Durandal? Data Entry kit demonstrates several basic form scenarios, elements and utilities.';
  this.features = [
      new feature('Scenarios', ['Log-in', 'User Registration', 'Data Entry','Data Entry Wizard' ,'Multiple/Nested VM Data Entry']),
      new feature('Elements', ['Dates', 'Radio Buttons', 'Checkboxes']),
      new feature('Utilites', ['Validation','Field Enable/Disable'])
  ];
};

var feature = function (feature, elements) {
  this.feature = feature;
  this.elements = elements;
}

ko.applyBindings(landing);
```

html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: features">
   <li data-bind="text: feature">
     <ul data-bind="foreach: elements">
         <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` binding replaces all inner tags inside `li` with text, so

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: features">
   <li data-bind="text: feature">
     <ul data-bind="foreach: elements">   <!-- this tags are ignored -->
         <li data-bind="text:$data"></li> <!-- this tags are ignored -->
     </ul>                                <!-- this tags are ignored -->
 </li>
</ul>
```

is equal to

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: features">
   <li data-bind="text: feature"></li>
</ul>
```

So you can't use text binding for `li` if you have nested tags.
Use something like

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: features">
    <li>
       <span data-bind="text: feature"></span>
       <ul data-bind="foreach: elements">
           <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAQ6E/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that attribute data-bind="text: feature" rewrite inner logic

See work fix on your js feedle example at five version

```
[FIX](http://jsfiddle.net/K7kcc/5/)
```